# How to select the foreign key column without joining the tables in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

My application has two tables, namely "users" and "books" with one-many relationship. When the books are fetched, I want to check if a particular book is owned by the requester. But it seems that TypeORM doesn't allow me to just select the foreign key column (userId) without joining the tables using 'relation'. How can I avoid this since this would be costly to fetch the full records from users?

```
    const books = await this.repository.find({
            where: { user: { id: userId } },
            relation: ['user'],
          });
```

```
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.books)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
    user: User;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I've just figured it out from one of *GitHub discussions*. Here's how it's done.

Construct another column in the many-side entity of the relationship. In this case, it's **Book**.

```
@Column('int', { name: 'userId', nullable: true })
  userId: number;
```

Now, we can see the **userId** in the queries such as find. Thank you everyone for your time.